# Create context-sensitive admin menus for right-click

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, privileges

I've got a right-click explorer menu that allows me to open a file in Notepad++, which works pretty good.  Very convenient.  It takes a small registry hack (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell), but no worries... unless the file is in a protected folder requiring Admin access to write.

Is there a way to make a registry hack that allows me to right-click on a file and see an option to open the file in Notepad (I can figger out Notepad++) under administrative privileges?  It's OK if I get prompted for the elevation confirmation, I just want to right click on the file and be able to edit it.

Comment: There is a reason that programs are no longer run as admin by default: if anything goes wrong (bug, user error, etc.), you want to limit the damage.  In general, it is a bad idea to run anything as admin unless it is ABSOLUTELY necessary.  Just save a copy somewhere else, and move that to the protected location when you are done.  A bit of a hassle, yes, but it could potentially avoid a much larger problem later on down the road.  That is my two cents.  If you really want to do it anyway, just remember that I warned you.

Comment: I get that; I do.  But on some right-click options, it marks it as an administrative privilege-using task.  You have to allow it to run under elevated permissions.  I want to do the same thing for a custom task that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `runas` command as follows:
`runas /noprofile /user:SomeAdminUser notepad.exe %1`
A CMD window will open asking for the password of SomeAdminUser, after which notepad will launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SendTo submenu. Just put a shortcut in your SendTo folder that names the
program and elevation status desired in its Properties.